# PrintWriter.flush() doesn't cause output to be displayed on Mac

Tags: java, macos, servlets

I have a servlet that uses a PrintWriter to send data back to the browser.

[EDIT] This works without issue when client OS is linux (FF and curl). When client is Mac - nothing shows until stream is closed (FF,Chrome,curl).

I've searched for similar issues here and the answers are either use flush() or don't use the printWriter and the outputStream at the same time. However, neither of these apply to me.

When I hit the servlet with my browser, it shows nothing at all until the loop finishes and the writer is closed. Then everything that was printed shows up at once.

I've deployed this on a number of tomcat 8 servers with the same result.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) {

        String message = "Hello World ";
        response.setContentType( "text/html" );
        response.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );

        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = response.getWriter();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.println( "<HTML>" );
        out.println( "<HEAD><TITLE>Hello World Test</TITLE></HEAD>" );
        out.println( "<BODY>" );
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            out.println( "<h1>" + message + i + "</h1>" );
            out.flush();
            try {
                Thread.sleep( 5000 );
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                out.println( e );
            }
        }
        out.println( "</BODY>" );
        out.println( "</HTML>" );

        out.close();

        try {
            System.out.println("Writer is closed.");
            Thread.sleep( 5000 );
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. How exactly did it work earlier? It it works like it have to work. When you hit the servlet it send info to your server, then this method proceed it, writing output to response and when this method is done executing the tomcat will send response to your browser. One chick to servlet, one batch of data at a time. You can't get the data partial from one request(using this way)

Comment: So you expect that after the flush the browser shows the partial content? Seems like an undocumented feature. What is the use case for that? There may be several reasons that this behaviour changed. A new browser version, a proxy in between, new Tomcat version, etc. If you have a working setting you can change one thing at a time to find out why it doesn't work any more.

Comment: You're effectively trying to 'intervene' in (change) the http protocol by use of ```flush``` and ```sleep```. How would that work? You might be able to use a proper chunked response with a browser but I'm not sure if that would even work

Comment: Did you try using response.flushBuffer();  ?

Comment: Actually, this code is working and the issue is on the client side. Using tcpdump I can see that the messages are being sent back, just not being displayed. On my mac, I've used several clients including firefox, chrome, and curl.

Comment: I also have a linux client with firefox 103 on it and the page appears to work fine over there. Curl also works on the linux client and shows the messages as they come in.

Comment: Try `System.setProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");` Can it be that the server uses `"\n"` and the (old!) Mac uses `"\r"`? In everycase I would try `out.flush();` instead of `out.close();` which - as far as I remember - is the correct way.

Comment: No dice. Also, you see that I am calling flush() and not close(), at least until the end of the loop.